# Getting errors while parsing JSON using JSON.NET , windwos phone

Tags: c#, parsing, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, json.net

Im getting the following error when I try to parse JSON using JSON.NET in a windows phone project,

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`nTo fix this error either
>   change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the
>   deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type

My response object is like

```
{"classifieds_mst":
    [
    {"classified_id":27,
     "community_id":1,
     "community_name":"ietech_apartments",
     "classified_title":"hiii"},

     {"classified_id":14,
     "community_id":1,
     "community_name":"ietech_apartments",
     "classified_title":"hiii"}
    ]
}
```

The class that I generate is

```
public class ClassifiedsMst
    {
        public int classified_id { get; set; }
        public int community_id { get; set; }
        public string classified_title { get; set; }
    }

public class Classified
{
    public List<ClassifiedsMst> classifiedsmst { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to parse like this

```
  Classified root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Classified>>(responseString)[0];
```

And Im getting the above error please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON string you posted represents a `Classified` instance, not a list of `Classified` objects.

You should change you `Classified` class like this:

```
public class Classified
{
    public List<ClassifiedsMst> classifieds_mst { get; set; }
}
```

And do:

```
Classified root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Classified>(responseString);
```